# Visual Basic 6: Finding references used by a particular control

Tags: vb6

I have a visual basic project with a large number of user controls and references. Is there an easy way to determine, for a particular control, which of the references it actually depends on? I already got the components it uses by looking at the ctl file in a text editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One trick I've done, is unchecked references until it errors on compile.  Load up the controls on their own and try to compile it.  You might have to add some auxiliary modules and classes, but this way you can quickly isolate things.

There's no specific way (other than looking through the control's code itself) to determine what the references are needed from the project.

Unrelated, but - the only thing you CAN effectively do is determine which forms require which ActiveX controls by comparing the GUIDs in the form (.frm) files with the GUIDs in the project (.vbp) files.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks!